# Cannot insert custom block into 'product.price.final' in XML

Tags: magento2, blocks, xml, final-price

Here is my catalog_product_view.xml:
I want to insert one CustomBlock to this final price block, so i can use getChildHtml() to call in template final_price.phtml, but it does not work so far, why ?

```
 <referenceBlock name="product.price.final">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom.block"  template="CustomModule::custom.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>
```

Comment: I think adding the custom block to the "product.info.price" block is better.

Comment: @WangGang I have tried "product.info.price", it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.price">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom.block"  template="CustomModule::custom.phtml" after="product.price.final" />
    </referenceBlock>
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I asked. I need to inject my template below 'old-price' element in final_price.phtml.
I noticed the normal XML method does not work as expected, so I would like to know how price rendered in Magento and how to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using view model for same

Comment: Can you give me one example ? Or point me which file in magento is using view model ?
Thanks !